# Sessions and refreshing

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

I want to update information of an user his session when he refreshes the site, is there any way this can be done using `express-session` - any way to detect when an user reconnected, or refreshed the site?

Comment: Have you thought about exposing an endpoint (for example `/session-update`) and hiting on page load / on online event?

Comment: @Volodymyr I currently just run middleware for it, I have not thought of that no.